# How to by-pass cloud function call and serve it from cdn from firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a web application written in Firebase and I am deploying it to Firebase hosting.
In the web application, I am calling a cloud function which returns kind of static data(data changes in a day or two).
Is it possible to bypass the cloud function call execution and serve it directly through Firebase global CDN.
This is what I already tried in firebase json.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "flutter",
    "public": "build/web",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600'"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/getData/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
{
        "source": "https://us-central1-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/getData",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should review the [documentation on managing the cache behavior of Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache).

Your function needs to set a cache control header to indicate how long its response should be cached.  If it does that, then Firebase Hosting will serve the cached response until the specified expiration.

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
```

Comment: Thanks @doug-stevenson
That helped and worked .
However, I have one last concern to address. It seems that the cdn is caching data based on the browser. For instance, when I open the website in Chrome, it fetches the data initially, and subsequent requests are served from the CDN. However, if I switch to Safari, it fetches the data again from the Cloud Function before serving it from the CDN.

Is there a way to ensure that once the data is fetched, subsequent requests return data directly from the CDN regardless of the browser used?

Comment: You should ask a new question showing your code and debugging details, along with the steps that anyone can take to reproduce the issue.